# Prevent application to crash when unhandled exception in dll

Tags: c#, dll

I'm working on a C# WPF application. I'm using a DLL (not developed by me). I'm using it like this (simplified):

```
try
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(filePath);

    // Use the DLL
    var worker = theDLL.loadImage(bmp);

    status state = worker.start();

    if (state = theDLL.sta.OK)
    {
        return "OK"
    }
    else
    {
        state = worker.tryOtherMethod();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Do something with e
}
```

Sometimes (not always) I have a Unhandled exception. This exception is not catch and my application crash :

> An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid
>   parameters fatal.

I saw that this exception comes from C++ code but i'm unable to catch it (even with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` or `Dispatcher.UnhandledException`).

How can I prevent the crash ?

**Edit:**

I've try to catch the exception with `catch` alone and `catch (Win32Exception e)` but both didn't solve my problem.

I still have this error :

[image]

Comment: Do you get the problem sometimes with the same file, or with different files?  Is it possible you are passing a corrupt or invalid file to the function.

Comment: @Neil I've try with many file, a file can work well one time, and crash the next time (in same run or different run).

Comment: Yes, the C++ runtime can generate this diagnostic.  It cannot be caught, it is not thrown as an exception and will failfast the entire process.  Technically the C++ code can [use this function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9yf33zb.aspx) to change that behavior, but it is not like that will produce a better outcome.  It is always a programming bug and exceptions don't fix bugs.